# How to create responsive list items using bootstrap theme

Tags: theming

I am using bootstrap theme. I am trying to create responsive list items. When viewing the page in tablet, laptop, desktop, I would like to see items in two columns.  When viewing the page in mobile, list should display in a single column. I entered the below code in body field but it is not working for me. I googled for some bootstrap classes but I could not find anything specific. Can you please advise how I can write the code to create responsive list items?

```
<table>
<tr> <td class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> 
<ul>
<li>Probate Problems</li>
  <li>Title Issues</li>
  <li>Foreclosure</li>
  <li>Liens</li>
  <li>Judgements</li>
  <li>Code Violations</li>
  <li>Job Transfer</li>
</ul></td>
<td class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">  <ul>
  <li>Mold</li>
  <li>Divorce</li>
  <li>Tenants Issues</li>
  <li>Behind on Taxes</li>
  <li>Fire Damage</li>
  <li>Foundation Problems</li>
  <li>Run-down Properties</li>
</ul></td></tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use the Bootstrap column classes with divs instead of table elements, inside of a "row" element, which must be inside a "container" element:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <!-- Your first column goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <!-- Your second column goes here -->
  </div>
</div> <!-- End row -->
</div> <!-- End container -->
```

There is [more information about using the Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in the main Bootstrap page.

Comment: You can also use container-fluid class instead of container if you want fluid layout. Also col-lg-6 and col-md-6 are not required in this example.